# split string separated by commas and equal sign in php with escaping

Tags: php, regex, pcre

I want to split a string like this:

```
colors = blue, green, yellow, kinda violet\, not sure,purple\=almost magenta
```

With regular expression so the result should be

```
colors
blue
green
yellow
kinda violet\, not sure
purple\=almost magenta
```

I've been trying for hours but didn't succeed with ugly constructions like this (for preg_match_all):

```
/(.*)\s*[=]\s*((.+)\s*,\s*)*/
```

and this (for preg_split)

```
/\s*[=,^(\\,)^(\\=)]\s*/
```

Please, explayne what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You would need negative lookbehind [assertions](http://www.php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.assertions.php):

```
$s = 'colors = blue, green, yellow, kinda violet\, not sure,purple\=almost magenta';

$res = preg_split('/(?<!\\\\)[,=]\s*/', $s);

print_r($res);
```

Basically it matches a comma (or equal sign) followed by an optional sequence of space characters BUT ONLY if there's no backslash preceding it.

Comment: Thank you so much! You made my day :) *reads about assertions*

Answer (score 1):

Not very elegant, but this should do the trick with preg_split

```
/(\s*=\s*)|(\s*,\s*)|(\s*\\=\s*)|(\s*\\,\s*)/g
```

Most importantly, don't forget the g at the end for global matching.

Comment: The g modifier doesn't exist in pcre, were you mixing it up with JavaScript regex? :)